# Write binary file C from unsigned char

Tags: c

I'm making a program that writes a binary file, the content of this binary file are in an unsigned char pointer. The next code is the way that I using to generate the binary

```
while (f > 0) {
    oct = (unsigned char) *datosOct->informacion++;

    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {   
        char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');
        temporal = appendCharToCharArray(temporal, actual);
    }           
    f--;
}
datosBin->informacion = (unsigned char*)temporal;
```

I had used `fopen` in mode wb, but it literals write a file with 1s and 0s. this is the function that I use to write (I using the default compiler of Visual Studio). I use the next code to write the file

```
file = fopen(nombreArchivo, "wb");
fwrite(datosBin->informacion, sizeof(char), archivoEnOctal->tamanio, file);
```

My starting point is a char array that contains `'1'`s and `'0'`s, each byte of '1's and '0's represents an `ASCII` value. For example, `'1010000'` is the ASCII 80 representing the letter 'P', if I transforms the binary char array ('1010000') to an array of chars ('P') when it finds values whose ASCII is 00 takes them as the end of the text and does not write them to the final file. One of the possible outputs of my code is an image, so I need to write these values 00. I tried this to write the chars directly, but this doesn't work for the images for the reason I mentioned before

```
while (f > 0) {
    oct = (unsigned char) *datosOct->informacion++;

    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {   
        if (size == 8) {
            size = 0;
            char nuevaLetra = strtol(temporal, 0, 2); 
            if (nuevaLetra == 00) {
                nuevaLetra = '\0';
                //nuevaLetra = (char) 0;
            }
            response = appendCharToCharArray(response, nuevaLetra);
            temporal = (char*)"";
        }
        size++;
        char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0);
        temporal = appendCharToCharArray(temporal, actual);
    }           
    f--;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Writing only binary, or not even binary? `char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');` assigns the *character* `'0'` or `'1'` not the *value* `0` or `1`.

Comment: The program is literally writing the char '1' and '0' but I need the program writes the binary values, for example, the program writes '01010000', the expected output is P

Comment: Just write the byte.

Comment: Weather Vane, if i use char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0); the program writes me, the ascci values for 1 and 0

Comment: @juanjosemontoya - The code `char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0);` is not the same as `char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');` - your last comment is untrue.

Comment: @enhzflep when I use the char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0'); my outup is a file with  character '0' or  '1' , but when I use char actual = ((oct & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0); I get a file whit the  ascii values of 0 and 1, twice ways are not my expecter output.

Comment: But `'0'` is the ASCII value of the character, 48. `0` is the value 0. It's not very clear what is being asked.

Comment: What i understand is that he is saving the binary 01010000 on the char*, and when he writes it to the file is literary writing '01010000', but expecting the ASCII 80, that means the letter "P" which is the expected output.

Comment: @juanjosemontoya - uh-huh. I know. Why aren't you just keeping an accumulator and a count of the number of bits in it? You compute a 1 or a 0, left/right shift the accumulator, OR in the new bit and increment your bitCount. Once it reaches 8, you write out the char, clear the accumulator and reset the count.

Comment: @enhzflep I tried that before, I update the post for explaining it

Comment: @juanjosemontoya - your post discussed no such thing. The accumalator I'm talking about is 8bit wide - a single char. You need to use bitwise operators to manipulate it. Also , 10100000b is not Ascii 80. It is 160d or 0xA0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave it to you to build and run it, before looking inside output.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char data;
    unsigned char numBitsValid;
} bitAccumalator_t;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "wb");
    char *inputStream = "011001000110111101100101011100110010000001110100011010000110100101110011001000000110100001100101011011000111000000111111";
    int numBits = strlen(inputStream);
    bitAccumalator_t outBuffer = {0,0};
    for (int i=0; i<numBits; i++)
    {
        outBuffer.data <<= 1;
        if (inputStream[i] == '1')
        {
            outBuffer.data |= 1;
        }
        outBuffer.numBitsValid++;

        if (outBuffer.numBitsValid == 8)
        {
            fwrite(&outBuffer.data, 1, 1, fp);
            outBuffer.data = 0;
            outBuffer.numBitsValid = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow impressive, could you please explain us a little bit how you code works? I'm newbie in C

Comment: @JohnGuzman - try stepping through the code with a debugger. It puts either 1 or 0 into the least significant bit of an accumalator until it has filled the byte. Once done, it writes that byte to the output. `<<=` and `|=` are bitwise operators. 00000001b << 1 = 00000010b. Next, 00000010b | 1 = 00000011b. As the output.txt asks, does this help?

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Now my question is, this should works as well if we save those chars to an array and then writing them all to the file instead of writing to the file one by one?

Comment: @JohnGuzman - yes, absolutely. That's the preferred method - I just wanted to provide an easy to digest answer.

Comment: regarding: `outBuffer.data |= 1;`  This is always going to set the same bit.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest inserting, before that statement: `outBuffer.data <<= 1;`

Comment: @user3629249 - yes, it sets the LSB (which has just been vacated by the shift left) if and only if a 1 is found in the stream. The operation that happens last is setting the bit. This is correct. Your suggestion would mean the LSB didn't hold anything useful at the time the byte was written. ;)